Снять задачу в диспетчере задач Windows с помощью Python?
Мне нужно чтобы отдельный exe файл закрывал основную программу. Я думал решить это через снятие задачи в диспетчере, но никак не могу найти как это можно реализовать.

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как задать хороший вопрос

видимо надо смотреть в pywin32 в модуле win32process

Если вопрос касается только windows, то в Вашем случае, намного проще будет убить процесс через taskkill в  subprocess. Пример:
subprocess.call(["taskkill","/F","/IM","chrom.exe"])

Ключ /F - принудительно закроет программу, ключ /IM - указывает название приложения.
Более подробнее о taskkill.
